# How to get date in month-year format?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I got the data from someone which has following types of dates:

`"Jan-20", "Feb-19", "May-18"`

I want to convert them into following format:

`"01-20", "02-19", "05-18"`

But whenever I try to convert the column to `as.date` it returns NA values.

e.g.

```
df<- data.frame(MonthYear = c("Jan-20", "Feb-19", "May-18"))
df$MonthYear<-as.Date(df$MonthYear, format = "%b-%y")
```

Output:

```
MonthYear
1      <NA>
2      <NA>
3      <NA>
```

So I used the following code and added day as well. But I don't want the date:

```
df<- data.frame(MonthYear = c("Jan-20", "Feb-19", "May-18"))
df$MonthYear<-paste(as.character(df$MonthYear))
df$MonthYear<-paste("01-",as.character(df$MonthYear))
df$MonthYear<-as.Date(df$MonthYear, format = "%d- %b-%y")
```

Output:

```
MonthYear
1 2020-01-01
2 2019-02-01
3 2018-05-01
```

But my required output is as follows:

```
MonthYear
1 2020-01
2 2019-02
3 2018-05
```

Comment: If you just want to convert `"Jan-20"` to `"01-20"`, you can can also substitute based on a regular expression such as: `stringr::str_replace_all(c("Jan-20", "Feb-19", "May-18"), setNames(sprintf("%02d", 1:12), month.abb))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `as.yearmon()` from the zoo package (and the magrittr pipe):

```
library(zoo)
library(magrittr)
as.yearmon(df$MonthYear, "%b-%y") %>%
 format(., "%Y-%m")


[1] "2020-01" "2019-02" "2018-05"
```

Can also be done without the '.' used as a placeholder for the left hand side of the pipe.  It was left in as these functions aren't typical tidyverse piping functions.

```
as.yearmon(df$MonthYear, "%b-%y") %>%
 format("%Y-%m")
```

Or without piping at all, and using nested functions (as pointed out by @Sotos).  I find them harder to read, and usually have the tidyverse (and therefore %>% pipes) loaded anyway.

```
format(as.yearmon(df$MonthYear, "%b-%y"), "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Why load an extra package for the pipe?? Why not just `format(as.yearmon(...), '%Y-%m')`?

Comment: The magrittr pipe certianly isn't necessary, and you make a good point.  I generally have the tidyverse loaded, and it shows in how I think about solutions to problems.

Comment: I think this is clearer, it is hard to parse information when it is nested, so even with the extra package this solution in my opinion is just as good, it is a matter of preference, the cognitive load of packages (which you get accustomed to) or the cognitive load of nesting functions and using non-specialized functions.

Comment: Including the dot in `format(., "%Y-%m")` is confusing, since it isn't needed, and there are special rules for handling dots.

Answer (score 2):

You could paste an arbitrary date, convert to Date and then use `format`

```
format(as.Date(paste0("01-",df$MonthYear), "%d-%b-%y"), "%Y-%m")
#[1] "2020-01" "2019-02" "2018-05"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following using `gsub()` to keep the year and month only, i.e.,

```
format(gsub("(.*)-\\d+","\\1",df$MonthYear),format = "%Y-%m")
```

or just

```
gsub("(.*)-\\d+","\\1",df$MonthYear)
```

such that

```
[1] "2020-01" "2019-02" "2018-05"
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(MonthYear = structure(c(18262, 17928, 17652), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c("Jan-20", "Feb-19", "May-18")
for (i in seq_along(month.abb)) x <- sub(month.abb[i], sprintf("%02d", i), x) 
# Can add fixed = TRUE for speed

x
# [1] "01-20" "02-19" "05-18"
```

Comment: add context so we can learn from it or you end up in winning the Low-Quality Post Review Award 2019! That gets your answer removed. (End of Review).